# CSS Sprite Compatibility in Firefox

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a div element that uses the css classes below. Basically, I'm creating a sprite image link that changes on hover.

```
.home {
    background: url('images/home.png') 0 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 188px;
    border: none;   
}

.home:hover {
    background-position: -150px 0;  
}
```

When I tested it with different browsers, it seemed to work well with most browsers except for some versions of Firefox. On hover, it doesn't switch the img position. As I read from w3c for this to work in Firefox, the "background-attachment" property to "fixed". I did this and added the property to both classes and still didn't work. When I added the property, the image was centered, and whatever was not within the specified width and height were cut off.

Comment: works fine for me in Firefox 3.6 and 4

Comment: Can you recreate the problem so that we can see it? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I do it this way since 2008 and always worked well (Firefox 3, 4, 5, 6). On what Firefox versions and what OS do you have problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, it looks like I forgot to add the DOCTYPE tag at the beginning at the file, which contributed to the thing not working in FF.

Added

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess without seeing the problem, but sometimes using the background shorthand can be buggy in FF:

try :

```
.home {
  backround-image: url('images/home.png');
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 188px;
  border: none;
}

.home:hover {
  background-position: -150px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to have `no-repeat` for background image. Firefox works fine with `background-position` but `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` wont work. I don't know what you are willing to do for which element, but it should work on block elements only. If it's not a block element, `display: block` is required

```
.home {
    background: url('images/home.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 188px;
    border: none;   
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 background-position: 0px 0px;
 background-position: -150px 0px;
```

Comment: Try to specify a bit more where to use those CSS attributes and how it answers the question

Comment: It's generally a good idea to explain why+how your solution works.. for the benefit of onlooking n00bs that don't understand :)